# java testing generics with dynamic generic type

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics

I'm writing junit3 tests. I want to create a generic testing method (`assertIteratorThrowsNoSuchElement` below) which can take my generic structure as 1st param and the generic type as 2nd param. That is because I want to check if the exception is thrown correctly once for string, then for integers and again for my own custom type. This is the code I've got now:

```
public void testEmptyIteratorException () {
    Deque<String> deque = new Deque<String>();
    assertIteratorThrowsNoSuchElement(deque, String.class);
}

private void assertIteratorThrowsNoSuchElement(Deque<T> deque, Class<T> cl) {
    Iterator<T> iter = deque.iterator();
    try {
        iter.next();
        fail();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException expected) {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

The compiler dislikes:

```
The method assertIteratorThrowsNoSuchElement(Deque<T>, Class<T>) from the type DequeTest refers to the missing type T // the first method

Multiple markers at this line // the second method
- T cannot be resolved to a type
- T cannot be resolved to a type
```

My question is - what's the error in above code and how should it be done?

Comment: `assertTrue(true);` is useless, also if `Deque` is java one, the test is useless, you usually test your code, not the JDK one

Comment: it's a matter of taste ;)

Comment: If you can use JUnit 4, then you can pass the expected exception to the `@Test` annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the type parameter for that method before using it. To create a generic method, you declare the type parameter before the return type:

```
private <T> void assertIteratorThrowsNoSuchElement(Deque<T> deque, Class<T> cl) {
}
```

Also, I don't see any use of the 2<sup>nd</sup> parameter there. You're not even using it. The type parameter `T` is automatically inferred from the actual type you're passing. If you've added it for that purpose, then you can remove it. Just keep the 1<sup>st</sup> parameter.

Comment: Ok, the `<T>` in method header does the job and the second parameter is useless now, I thought you just do it other way (like in scripting langauges). Thanks.

Comment: Just one more question - now I write `assertIteratorThrowsNoSuchElement(deque);` and the compiler is happy with that. Does the compiler fetch the `<T>` type from the generic of the deque object? What if I had more than one generic type?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz Yes it would. If you have more than one generic type parameter, and if they has to be different, then you use different type parameters.